# Unable to get percentage with 'int' even though value is within range. Works with 'long' though. Why?

Tags: c, integer, long-integer

Can anyone explain to me why is util2=49, but util1=5?

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int load1 = 47759534;
int capacity1 = 96000000;

long load2 = 47759534;
int capacity2 = 96000000;

int util1 = (100*load1)/capacity1;
int util2 = (100*load2)/capacity2;

printf("util1 = %d\n", util1);
printf("util2 = %d\n", util2);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
util1 = 5
util2 = 49
```

I understand that 'int' is at least 16 bits and 'long' is at least 32 bits but load1 in the above snippet is within the common range of int and long, i.e, 2,147,483,647.  Why is util1 rounded off to 5 then?

Comment: `47759534 * 100` requires 33 bits.

Comment: 47759534*100 overflows an `int` type.

Comment: It won't work with `long` when an implementation has 32-bit `long` (as MS VC).

Answer (score 3):

In C, int is usually 32 bits. Let's assume that is the case here. When you multiply by 100, the result in binary is:

000100011100101010110100001111111000

Since that is more than 32 bits, the most significant bits get discarded. If you take the lowest 32 bit you get
00011100101010110100001111111000 = 480,986,104

If you divide that by 96000000 you'll get 5.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks so much!

Comment: Unless speed is an issue, converting to float or double, dividing, then converting (and rounding correctly) back to int or long will probably be more reliable.

Comment: That behaviour is well defined for unsigned integers, but C does not define what happens when **signed** integers overflow.

Comment: Re “Since that is more than 32 bits, the most significant bits get discarded”: The C standard does not define the behavior when overflow occurs. It is fine to describe the behavior of particular compilers, particularly if they explicitly define it (in which case a citation should be provided), but it should not be asserted as the behavior in C without qualification.

Answer (score 0):

> to get percentage

- Make certain the multiply does not overflow - which is *undefined behavior* (UB) with *signed* integers.  `int` is at least 16-bit.  `long` is at least 32-bit.  `long long` is at least 64-bit.  Since `47759534 * 100` is a 33-bit product, use at least 64-bit math.

```
    // int util1 = (100*load1)/capacity1;
    long long util1 = (100LL*load1)/capacity1;
    // printf("util1 = %d\n", util1);
    printf("util1 = %lld\n", util1);
```

- Integer division truncates.  To get a rounded answer, for positive numbers, add half the divisor, then divide

```
    long long util1 = (100LL*load1 + capacity1/2)/capacity1;
    printf("util1 = %lld\n", util1);
```

---

Advanced: To handle negatives, mixed signed dividend/divisors and rounding ties to even can still use integer math, yet needs more code.